# way to remove global variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I know I can view all global variable through Kernel#global_variables but is there any method for removing them akin to the remove_instance_variable, remove_class_variable, remove_const methods? Or is there a way to use those to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I don't think so. (Why would you want to?)

Comment: You can assign a `nil` value to it. But, like the comments, why would you want to define and remove a global variable? Global variables should be avoided as they can be overridden from anywhere in the code. If you have to use them, use them with extreme prudence.

Comment: Due to gc delays ObjectSpace#define_finalizer may not be immediate enough to know when an object is no longer referenced by a variable. Kernel#trace_var, the only callback that fires when a variable is changed, only works on globals

Comment: and sometimes using a setter function isn't practical or possible for numerous reasons

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's possible to "unset" a global variable. Your best bet is setting the variable to `nil`.

Normally, when you try to use a variable you haven't defined yet, Ruby throws an error.

```
irb > "The following variable has not yet been defined: #{a}"
irb > NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

This behavior is actually different with global variables. Any attempt to call a global variable that hasn't been defined will return `nil`.

```
irb > "The following global variable has not yet been defined: #{$a}"
  # => The following global variable has not yet been defined: 
irb > $a.class
  # => NilClass
```

So setting your global variable to nil should have exactly the same behavior that you would expect from "unsetting" it.